# What exactly is Android 4.4W vs 4.4 - and what about 5.0.1?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am a bit confused on the difference between Android 4.4 Kitkat, and Android 4.4W. I know the "w" version is for my Moto 360, I have been developing for some time now.

But, I can't seem to find any good resource on what 4.4W actually is compared to the regular 4.4.

After the 5.0.1 rollout to wear devices I am even more confused. Were the 4.4W just a temporary thing? Do Android 5.0.1 (API level 21) consolidate the OS on wearables and hendhelds?

Comment: **W** stands for **Wearable**

Comment: I know that. But is W a different Build of the OS? Are all the same APIs present? What is different, if anything?

Answer (score 2):

The Android API levels are explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) . If you scroll down to 'What is API Level?' this will detail the versions of API that are available for your app to target (I think Android wear needs to target 4.3 and above).

4.4w is as you say a wearable API level that was release prior to 5.0 (Lollipop) as an update of the API to include the Android Wear API's.  These Android Wear API's are now part of the 5.0 release.

The Android wear watches moved from 4.4w to 5.0 to reflect these changes at the end of last year.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the consolidated API versions on 5.0.1 

What I am trying to figure out is if it is the same build of Android 5.0.1 that runs on both the wearable and the handheld? Will I will be able to use exactly the same APIs on the wearable?

Comment: Journalists also write sentences like "Android 5.0.1 for Android Wear" (http://www.droid-life.com/2014/12/19/tip-you-can-take-easier-screenshots-in-android-wear-5-0-1/) - what does that really mean? What is the relationship between android wear and android_

Comment: The wearable has its own set of API's (see here > http://developer.android.com/reference/packages-wearable-support.html ) and it runs a cut down version of Android optimised for the wearable devices.

Comment: The API reference you mention, is for the support library you include when you develop Watch specific things like UI, watch faces etc. 

I am trying, but having a hard time figuring out what "a cut down version of android, optimized for wearable devices" mean. What exactly is cut down?

Answer (score 2):

`Android 5.0.1 Lollipop`

- A few bugfixes, including resolving issues with video playback and password failures handling

---

`Android 4.4W` extends support for `Wearables`.

- Initial release of Android Wear platform for smartwatches
- UI updates for Google Maps navigation and alarms
- Offline music playback
- GPS support

---

`Android 4.4 Kitkat`

- Refreshed interface with white elements instead of blue

  Clock no longer shows bold hours; all digits are thin. The H, M, and S markings for the stopwatch and timer have been removed, leaving just the numbers.

  Ability for applications to trigger translucency in the navigation and status bars

  Ability for applications to use "immersive mode" to keep the navigation and status bars hidden while maintaining user interaction

  Action overflow menu buttons are always visible, even on devices with a "Menu" key, which was officially deprecated by Android 4.0.

  Optimizations for performance on devices with lower specifications, including zRAM support and "low RAM" device API

  Wireless printing capability

  NFC host card emulation, enabling a device to replace smart cards

  WebViews now based on Chromium engine (feature parity with Chrome for Android 30)

  Expanded functionality for notification listener services

  Public API for developing and managing text messaging clients

  New framework for UI transitions

  Storage Access Framework, an API allowing apps to retrieve files in a consistent manner. As part of the framework, a new system file picker allows users to access files from various sources (including those exposed by apps, such as online storage services).

  Sensor batching, step detector and counter APIs

  Settings application now makes it possible to select default text messaging and home (launcher) application

  Audio tunneling, audio monitoring and loudness enhancer

  Built-in screen recording feature (primarily for developers, as usage of ADB is required)

  Native infrared blaster API

  Expanded accessibility APIs and system-level closed captioning settings

  Android Runtime (ART) introduced as a new experimental application runtime environment, not enabled by default, as a replacement for the Dalvik virtual machine

  Bluetooth Message Access Profile (MAP) support

  Disabled access to battery statistics by third-party applications

  Settings application no longer uses a multi-pane layout on devices with larger screens

  Wi-Fi and mobile data activity (TX/RX) indicators are moved to quick settings

  Browser text wrap is disabled.